# How can I include individual javascript files in jsDependencies when using ScalaJSPlugin with SBT?

Tags: sbt, scala.js

I'm trying use 'ProvidedJS' like this:

```
jsDependencies ++= Seq(
  ...,
  ProvidedJS / "my-script.js"
)
```

and put the javascript file under `src/main/resources`

Getting the following error:

```
(client/compile:scalaJSPreLinkClasspath)
org.scalajs.core.tools.classpath.JSLibResolveException: 
Some references to JS libraries could not be resolved:
- Missing JS library: my-script.js
```

Comment: I am assuming this is `jsDependencies ++= Seq(...)`. This is the right way of having provided dependencies (supposing that your script is actually called `my-script.js`). There seems to be some larger issue with your build, could you post some more detail (or even better, reduce your build to a minimal example)?

Answer (score 1):

just put it into `./src/main/resources/my-script.js`

Comment: Please explain why this is the case, so future users may be able to better understand the answer!

Comment: I am using skcala.js 0.6.22 which allows using `ProvidedJS` in zlibraryDependencies` and looks for mentioned `.js` files in `src/main/resources/`. In my case scala.js files are in `src/main/scala`

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-jsdependencies" % "1.0.2")` and `addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "1.5.0")` to **plugins.sbt**
2. Add `jsDependencies += ProvidedJS / "my-script.js"` to settings project in **build.sbt**
3. Put your file to `/src/main/resources/my-script.js`
4. run `sbt clean compile fastOptJS`
5. Search your file `<project_dir>/target/scala-2.12/<your_project>_js-jsdeps.js`